# Swiper next and previous buttons not showing in Vue.js

Tags: css, vue.js

I'm trying to build a swiper with previous, active and next buttons and make other buttons not visible. I tried many combination and none of them worked. I'm using swiper package which version is `9.3.0`. What do I need to do?

HTML code:

```
<div class="blog-slider__pagination swiper-pagination-clickable swiper-pagination-bullets swiper-slide-active">
    <span class="swiper-pagination-bullet swiper-button-prev" tabindex="0" role="button" aria-label="Go to slide 1"></span>
    <span class="swiper-pagination-bullet" tabindex="0" role="button" aria-label="Go to slide 2"></span>
    <span class="swiper-pagination-bullet" tabindex="0" role="button" aria-label="Go to slide 3"></span>
    <span class="swiper-pagination-bullet swiper-button-next" tabindex="0" role="button" aria-label="Go to slide 4"></span>
</div>
```

Here is CSS:

```
.swiper-button-next,
.swiper-button-prev {
      width: 11px;
      height: 11px;
      display: block;
      border-radius: 10px;
      background: #062744;
      opacity: 0.2;
        transition: all .3s;
        &-active {
          opacity: 1;
          background: #747474;
          height: 30px;
          box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px rgba(109, 109, 109, 0.3);
          
          @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
            height: 11px;
            width: 30px;
          }
        }
    }
.swiper-pagination-bullet:not(.swiper-pagination-bullet-active):not(.swiper-button-prev):not(.swiper-button-next) {
      display: none;
    }
```

JavaScript swiper properties:

```
export default {
  name: 'Home',
    components: {
      Swiper
    },
  methods:{
  },
  mounted(){
    const swiper = new Swiper('.blog-slider', {
      spaceBetween: 30,
      effect: 'fade',
      direction: 'horizontal',
      loop: true,
      mousewheel: {
        invert: false,
      },
      // autoHeight: true,
      pagination: {
        el: '.blog-slider__pagination',
        clickable: true,
      }
    });
    
  }
}
```

As a result now I'm getting just active button as visible.

Answer (score 0):

You have both *display: block;* and *dispay: none;* in your CSS rule for *.swiper-button-next* and *.swiper-button-prev* classes.

Do you need these buttons visible? If so, then just remove *display: none;* from the rule.

Comment: I need previous and next classes visible, but when I do it it's still the same. Is maybe this something wrong with swiper version that doesn't support `.swiper-button-prev` and `.swiper-button-next` to autogenerate previous and next elements?

Comment: Do you remove `display: none` from `.swiper-button-next,
.swiper-button-prev` rule?

Comment: Yeah I did, again nothing happened, only active element is displayed

Comment: Well, you mentioned you use Vue. Can you please provide your component's full code? You can edit your question to do it.

Comment: Sure! I updated my question, maybe it's more clear now.